# ElasticSearch: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to add in a new field mapping, categories, in Kibana:

```
PUT testcats/items/_mapping
{
    "settings": {
},
    "mappings": {
    "items" : {
        "_meta" : {
        "version" : "33"
        },
        "dynamic_templates" : [
        {
            "numbers" : {
            "match_mapping_type" : "long",
            "mapping" : {
                "type" : "double"
            }
            }
        },
        {
            "floats" : {
            "match_mapping_type" : "double",
            "mapping" : {
                "type" : "double"
            }
            }
        },
        {
            "strings" : {
            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
            "mapping" : {
                "fields" : {
                "raw" : {
                    "ignore_above" : 256,
                    "type" : "keyword"
                }
                },
                "type" : "text"
            }
            }
        }
        ],
        "properties" : {
        "categories": {
            "properties": {
            "audio": {
                "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                    }
                },
                "source": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "store": false,
                    "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            },
            "user_generated": {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                "raw" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
                },
                "copy_to" : [
                "all_search_data_items"
                ],
                "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
            },
            "visual": {
                "properties": {
                "category": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                    }
                },
                "source": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "store": false,
                    "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

But then I get the response:

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
    {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  
[settings : {}] [mappings : {items={_meta={version=33},                          
dynamic_templates=[    {numbers={match_mapping_type=long, mapping= . 
{type=double}}}, {floats={match_mapping_type=double, mapping= . 
{type=double}}}, {strings=    {match_mapping_type=string, mapping= . 
{fields={raw={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}}}], 
properties={categories={properties=     {audio={properties={category= . 
{type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}}, source= . 
{type=text, store=false, fields={raw=    {type=keyword, 
ignore_above=256}}}}}, user_generated={type=text, fields={raw= . 
{type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}, copy_to=   [all_search_data_items], 
analyzer=autocomplete}, visual={properties={category={type=text, 
fields={raw={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}},    source={type=text, 
store=false, fields={raw={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}}}}}}}}}]"
    }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  
[settings : {}] [mappings : {items={_meta={version=33}, 
dynamic_templates=[    {numbers={match_mapping_type=long, mapping= . 
{type=double}}}, {floats={match_mapping_type=double, mapping= . 
{type=double}}}, {strings=    {match_mapping_type=string, mapping= . 
{fields={raw={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, type=text}}}], 
properties={categories={properties={audio=    {properties={category= . 
{type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}}, source= . 
{type=text, store=false, fields={raw={type=keyword,     
ignore_above=256}}}}}, user_generated={type=text, fields={raw= . 
{type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}, copy_to= . [all_search_data_items],     
analyzer=autocomplete}, visual={properties= . {category={type=text, 
fields={raw={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}}, source={type=text,     
store=false, fields={raw={type=keyword, ignore_above=256}}}}}}}}}}]"
},
"status": 400
}
```

I've been banging my head on this for a while.  I can't determine which parameter is unsupported.  Any help is appreciated!  Also, is there any way to get more detail from Kibana on the specific parameter is unsupported?

Comment: What is the current mapping? Try PUT testcats/_mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with only `PUT testcats` as action. You are passing settings that are also at the index level, not only at the mapping level.